# Recompute 3D coordinates of points in 2D image with depth map

Tags: 3d, coordinates, projection, projection-matrix

I'm fairly new to graphics and vision, and have some problems figuring out how to compute 3D coordinates.
I am given a image and would like to recompute the original coordinates for a certain pixel. I have the depth of that pixel as well as the camera position `(x_c, y_c, z_c)` and camera orientation `(x_o, y_o, z_o)`. This information alone is not enough in my understanding, since I need some form of focal length to get the angle of the pixel relative to the principal axis.

I have, however, a 4 by 4 camera projection matrix. First I do not understnd, why this matrix has the dimensions 4*4, since I always thought they should be 3*4. Second, I wanted to ask if there is a way to get the focal length from the projection matrix, or if there is a easier way to calculate the 3D coordinates than calculating the focal length and afterwards the line, on which the 3D point must be on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenCV use reprojectImage3d().  But you require QMatrix as a input.  You can generate that QMatrix during your rectification step.

You can refer the below sample for your reference, how to use this API.

https://github.com/bkornel/Reproject-Image-To-3D/blob/master/main.cpp